# Wine seemingly installed but not showing up in the menu

Tags: command-line, wine

I installed wine via terminal, following all the steps on the website, but it isnt showing up in the menu.. what do I do to troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: There's little reason to have wine by itself on the menu. You can make launchers for the programs you run with wine instead. To see if your installation worked, try typing `winecfg` in a terminal.

Comment: You do not need to. You never just run wine to look at it. Visit the Wine web site and see how it is used.